# Getting Actions must be plain objects error with my redux-observable epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

So I have an api that is using fromFetch like so:

```js
const myApi = () => {
  const data$ = fromFetch(url);
  return data$;
}
```

And my epic looks like so:

```js
export const fetchEpic = (action$: any) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.FETCH),
    mergeMap(action =>
      myApi().pipe(
        map(result => {
          console.log(result)
          return mapTo({ type: Actions.ADD_ITEMS, payload: result });
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
};
```

The console.log(result) seems to work without a hitch and no problem. However I am getting the error:

`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

As a side note I tried to do some basic testing and did this below and it worked fine so why is the epic above not working?

```js
export const fetchEpic = (action$: any) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.FETCH),
    mapTo({ type: Actions.ADD_ITEMS, payload: ['hello'] })
  );
};
```

Made a codesandbox of the above with same error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-visvesvaraya-b8oun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `map` block you should just return the action directly. Your code wraps it with `mapTo` which is an operator that should only be used inside a `pipe` method.
So your `fetchEpic` should be:

```
export const fetchEpic = (action$: any) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.FETCH),
    mergeMap(action =>
      myApi().pipe(
        map(result => {
          console.log(result)
          return{ type: Actions.ADD_ITEMS, payload: result };
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
};
```

Here is the updated code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-darkness-9dc9q

Since you're already using TypeScript, I found that many of such errors can actually found by the TypeScript compiler, if you type your epics correctly, e.g.

```
export const fetchEpic : Epic<YourActionType, YourActionType, YourStateType> = (action$) => { ..
```